# XLSM files parsing with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, parsing, xlsm

I am developing an application where the user can upload data from an Excel file. So I'm trying to parse a xlsm file (Excel file with macros), I've been looking for solutions. I've found [Maatwebsite](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel), that looked good but the problem is in the file that I parse there is some formulas. And that formulas give some PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception errors.

[image: Example of formula]

Here is my test function that does not work.

```
 public function displayExcel()
{
    $now = new DateTime('now');
    $excel = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex($now->format('m'))->load('public\my_file.xlsm', function ($reader) {
        $reader->select(array("AFFAIRE", "TOT."));
    })->get();

    var_dump($excel);
}
```

Thank you in advance for you help.

**Edit :**

When I am trying to parse the file I got that kind of error on  the cell that contains the formula above.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)?

Comment: Yep, I looked at that but the problem is the same. It does not support 'XSLM' files. Moreover i just find out that Maatwebsite does not either.

Comment: Maatwebsite is just a wrapper around PHPExcel.
PHPExcel and PHPSpreadsheet are the same thing, just different versions.
PHPSpreadsheet can read macro code and will preserve it (at least it says so on the documentation).

Comment: The Macro part doesn't seem to be your problem, though.
Can you please provide more info on WHAT errors you get with the formulas?

Comment: I don't think either that macros are the problem. I though that maybe the encoding of the informations were different between xlsx and xslm. I will edit my post.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to be able to import Excel formulas? If you just need the data CSV would be more appropriate.

Comment: I don't need the formulas but i got xlsm files. Are you suggesting that I export each to csv and then parse them ?

Comment: @AlexandreThyvador CSV will usually be easier to work with. I'd convert them to CSV unless there's a reason you can't. It's generally a lot easier to parse a text format like CSV than Excel files.

Comment: Also, CSV isn't vendor-specific. If Microsoft made changes to how Excel saves data, you may need to amend your application. Also some users might be using LibreOffice Calc or Gnumeric, or they might have pulled the data directly from a relational database. Under the circumstances CSV is going to be a safer bet since everything under the sun supports it.